# Redirect output of command to help when user input wrong arguments

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When user pass a incorrect number of arguments or wrong argument optionals incorrect, get a error from Symfony component.

```
php artisan migratedb:migrate acct --tables=pepe

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--tables" option does not exist.
```

It's possible redirect error to help instead?

```
php artisan migratedb:migrate acct --tables=pepe

Usage:
  migratedb:migrate [options] [--] <type>

Arguments:
  type                  full|table

Options:
      --table[=TABLE]    (multiple values allowed)
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Help:
 Migrate all o one table from setdart_oscom
```

Edit code for more explain:

```
...
protected $signature = 'migratedb:migrate 
                            {type : full|table}
                            {--table=*}';

public function fire()
{
        // Check arguments
        $this->checkArguments();
}

private function checkArguments()
{
        $type  = $this->argument('type');
        $table = $this->option('table');

        if (empty($table)) {
            echo "You must specify at least one table.".PHP_EOL;
            echo "Use: php artisan migratedb:migrate --help".PHP_EOL;
            //Artisan::call('migratedb:migrate', array('-h'=>true)); // NOT WORK
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Assuming you're running it from a `bash` (or bash compatible) shell and If it's ok to omit the output when the command is successful, you can do something like this: `php artisan migratedb:migrate acct --tables=pepe >& /dev/null || php artisian migratedb:migrate -h`

Comment: A lot of thanks for reply. But I don't looking for a solution with bash redirect. I'm looking for a technique with laravel.